# Replace unknown href="unknown" with href="" using SED

Tags: search, sed

I would like to search for all href="unknown url" and replace with href="" but the contents of the href= are all different. Some are /,http,https. How do you set a parameter around what you are searching for? This is for a Mac OSX.

```
sed -ie 's/href=".*?/"/href=””/g' hello.php
```

Comment: sed is not the right tool to parse html... and sed doesn't support non-greedy..

Answer (score 0):

In sed there is no non-greedy regexp. But usually you can use workaround.
In you case it's can be `href="[^"]*"` to match any url.

Also you can use any character after command `s`, that you don't need quote `/` unside regexp.
For example using `@`:

`s@href="https*://i.did.t.know.you[^"]*@href=""@g`

If you need mark several regexp for url same time you can use grouping `\( .. \)`
and OR `\|`

```
sed -ie 's|href="\([^"]*unknown.com/url[^"]*\|https*://another.unknown/url[^"]*\)"|href=""|g' hello.php
```